# Adding multiple resolution background

Tags: flutter, dart

I exported my background images from adobe XD (drawable hdpi folders) and I can't seem to figure out how to use them in my application, how should I go about the assets in the `pubspec.yaml` file?

I've tried editing the assets: in the pubspec but I'm not getting any result.

```
body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          ),
         ),
```

The code is for a single background image but I want all the drawable folder to be implemented.

Comment: did you add the `assets/images/` directory in the `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: stop debugging the start again

Comment: yes but it's saying: The asset directory assets/images/ does not exist.

Comment: never mind my assets folder was inside my lib folder, it's working now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter docs has it all covered.
Please check the following link:

[Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets)

Flutter will pick up the needed files automatically based on their names and occurencies in 2.0x / 3.0x folders that you put in the same folder as the original file.

Ex:

- assets/my-background.png

will result in a search for:

- assets/2.0x/my-background.png
- assets/3.0x/my-background.png

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the assets dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file, for instance

```
    assets:
          -images/background.png
```

Perform `packages get` once you do the above step.

Comment: Welcome to SO! May you please edit your answer a bit, add some explanations what you are doing and why.